# Play Services 7.0.0 can't upgrade on emulator

Tags: android-emulator, google-play-services

I upgraded our app to use Google Play Services 7.0.0 but now the app will not run on the emulator saying Play Services needs to be upgrade. But of course, the upgrade does not work.
Anyone know how to fix this or an ETA on the fix from Google ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest update to the emulator.

Comment: Which system image are you using?  I have the latest Google APIs ARM system image but it's still stuck on Google Play services 6.7.74.

Comment: I'm not sure about the ARM. Mine's an atom x86. Though it's still weird if ARM is behind atom.

Comment: I checked both Atom and Atom_64 5.1.1 images, but they still have 6.7.74.  Do you see 7.0.0 (or greater) when viewing the App info screen for Google Settings?

Comment: I found the issue: for some reason the 5.1.1 images are not updated.  But the Atom 5.0.1 image does have 7.0.97.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm using 7.5 release but the emulator doesn't have it, I'm using intel x86 image.